# Create an alias to print a command instead of executing it

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I'm just getting into customising my bash profile and I'm wondering how I can type an alias and bring it up on the cli without actually executing it. Using Curl as an example I'd like to type an alias and have something like:

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/agituser
```

come up on the CLI allowing me to edit the URL. Kind of like Autokey.

Comment: DId you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a variable `ONE` that holds the url `https://api.github.com/users/agituser`, you could use the following command to set an alias `editurl` that will give you an editable output:

```
alias editurl='read -e -i "$ONE" URL && curl $URL'
```

From `man read`:

```
NAME
       read - read from a file descriptor
```

- `-e` 
  If the standard input is coming from a terminal, Readline is used
  to obtain the line
- `-i text`    Use `TEXT` as the initial text for Readline

So `editurl` will give you,

```
ron@ron:~$ editurl 
https://api.github.com/users/agituser #this line is editable
```

You can change the url (which will be saved in `$URL) or not change.

If you do not change the url:

```
ron@ron:~$editurl 
https://api.github.com/users/agituser
{
  "login": "agituser",
  "id": 787606,
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/787606?v=3",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/agituser",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/agituser/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "public_repos": 0,
  "public_gists": 0,
  "followers": 0,
  "following": 0,
  "created_at": "2011-05-14T10:07:35Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-04-07T14:47:28Z"
}
```

or change the url:

```
ron@ron:~$editurl 
https://api.github.com/user
{
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Comment: @Moif Murphy If this post answered your questions you can mark it as the answer to your question